# How to insert an angular form data to a .Net backend that expects an autoincrement id

Tags: angular, .net-6.0

I'm trying to insert data into an SQL database using a .Net API endpoint. In the request body of my API endpoint, I get the following error which means the ID is auto incremental.

> status 500: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'StockFeed' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I'm able to insert data if I remove the ID field from the request body. If I try to insert data using my angular frontend I get the same error, even when I'm not adding the Id field,
How can I resolve this? I'm new to angular and .Net

In my api controller

```
[HttpPost("addfeed")]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateStockFeed([FromBody] Stock stockFeed)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    _dbContext.StockFeed.Add(stockFeed);
    await _dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetStockFeedById), new { id = stockFeed.Id }, stockFeed);
}
```

Models

```
   using System.Numerics;

namespace AuthAPI.Models
{
    public class Stock
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Int64 Company_id { get; set; }
        public Int64 Stockfeedtype_id { get; set; }
        public int  Installed_capacity { get; set; }
        public int Current_production { get; set; }
        public int Local_supply { get; set; }
        public int Exported { get; set; }
        public DateTime Production_date { get; set; }
        
    }
}
```

In angular in my component.ts file

```
//ngOnInit
this.stockFeedForm = this.fb.group({
      company_id: ['0', Validators.required],
      stockfeedtype_id:['', Validators.required],
      installed_capacity: ['', Validators.required],
      current_production:['', Validators.required],
      local_supply: ['', Validators.required],
      exported: ['', Validators.required],
    })
    

  onInsert() {
    if(this.stockFeedForm.valid){
      this.auth.addfeed(this.stockFeedForm.value)
       .subscribe({
        next:(res)=>{
          alert(res.message)
          this.stockFeedForm.reset();
          this.router.navigate(['stockFeed']);
        },
        error:(err)=>{
          alert(err.message)
        }
       })

      //  console.log(this.signupForm.value)
    }else{
      validateForm.validateAllFormFields(this.stockFeedForm);
      alert("Your form is invalid");
    }
  }
```

And html form

```
                       <div class="row">
                            <div class="panel-body p-3">
                                <div class="form-group pt-3">
                                    <label>Company</label>
                                    <select  (change)="changeCompany($event)" class="form-control">
                                        <option value="0">Select Company</option>
                                        <option [value]= "company.id" *ngFor = "let company of companyList">{{company.company_name}}</option>
                                    </select>
                            </div>
                           
                                <form [formGroup]="stockFeedForm">
                                <div class="form-group pt-3">
                                    <label>Company ID*</label>
                                    <div class="input-field" >
                                        <span class="fa fa-user p-2"></span>
                                        <input formControlName="company_id" type="text" placeholder="Company ID" [value]="selectedCompanyId" readonly>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <small *ngIf="stockFeedForm.controls['company_id'].dirty && stockFeedForm.hasError('required', 'company_id')" class="required-text text-danger">* Company is required</small>

                               

                                <div class="form-group pt-3">
                                    <div class="input-field" [class.error]="stockFeedForm.controls['stockfeedtype_id'].dirty && stockFeedForm.hasError('required', 'stockfeedtype_id')">
                                        <span class="fa fa-user p-2"></span>
                                        <input formControlName="stockfeedtype_id" type="text" placeholder="stockfeedtype_id">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <small *ngIf="stockFeedForm.controls['stockfeedtype_id'].dirty && stockFeedForm.hasError('required', 'stockfeedtype_id')" class="required-text text-danger">* Company is required</small>
                                    

                                    <div class="form-group pt-3">
                                        <div class="input-field" [class.error]="stockFeedForm.controls['installed_capacity'].dirty && stockFeedForm.hasError('required', 'installed_capacity')">
                                            <span class="fa fa-user p-2"></span>
                                            <input formControlName="installed_capacity" type="text" placeholder="Installed Capacity">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <small *ngIf="stockFeedForm.controls['installed_capacity'].dirty && stockFeedForm.hasError('required', 'installed_capacity')" class="required-text text-danger">* installed_capacity is required</small>
                                    <div class="form-group pt-3">
                                        <div class="input-field" [class.error]="stockFeedForm.controls['current_production'].dirty && stockFeedForm.hasError('required', 'current_production')">
                                            <span class="fa fa-envelope p-2"></span>
                                            <input formControlName="current_production" type="text" placeholder="current_production">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <small *ngIf="stockFeedForm.controls['current_production'].dirty && stockFeedForm.hasError('required', 'current_production')" class="required-text text-danger">* current_production is required</small>
                                    <div class="form-group pt-3">
                                        <div class="input-field" [class.error]="stockFeedForm.controls['local_supply'].dirty && stockFeedForm.hasError('required', 'local_supply')">
                                            <span class="fa fa-user p-2"></span>
                                            <input formControlName="local_supply" type="text" placeholder="local_supply ">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <small *ngIf="stockFeedForm.controls['local_supply'].dirty && stockFeedForm.hasError('required', 'local_supply')" class="required-text text-danger">* local_supply is required</small>
                
                                    
                                    <div class="form-group pt-3">
                                        <div class="input-field" [class.error]="stockFeedForm.controls['exported'].dirty && stockFeedForm.hasError('required', 'exported')">
                                            <span class="fa fa-lock p-2"></span>
                                            <input formControlName="exported" type="text" placeholder="exported">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <small *ngIf="stockFeedForm.controls['exported'].dirty && stockFeedForm.hasError('required', 'exported')" class="required-text text-danger">* exported is required</small>
                                    <button (click)="onInsert()" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block mt-4 w-100">Add</button>
                                    <!-- <div class="text-center pt-4 text-muted">Already have an account ? <a id="forget" routerLink="/login">Login</a></div>  -->
                                </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is, the API itself is still trying to insert an `Id`.

Your Angular front end is posting a model to your backend without the `Id` in the JSON payload, but the backend Controller is still deserializing the post data into your C# `Stock` model. Not including a property does not exclude it from the backend model, it will just make that property have a default value, in the case of a non nullable `int` it will be `0`

Try placing this attribute on top of the `Id` property of your model

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
```

as per
[https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/databasegenerated-dataannotations-attribute.aspx#:~:text=DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity,-You%20can%20mark&text=This%20specifies%20that%20the%20value,depends%20on%20the%20database%20provider](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/databasegenerated-dataannotations-attribute.aspx#:%7E:text=DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity,-You%20can%20mark&text=This%20specifies%20that%20the%20value,depends%20on%20the%20database%20provider).

> This specifies that the value of the property will be generated by the
> database on the INSERT statement. This Identity property cannot be
> updated.